# Randomizing position of correct answer in a quiz application for ios(Objective -C)

Tags: ios

I am trying to develop a simple quiz application for IOS. I need to pick up 10 random images out of 50 , and display each image and 4 options with one correct answer. Presently I am able to randomize images , but each time, the correct option is displayed only at one position. Can anyone help me for randomizing the position of correct answer for different questions (i.e, images)?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    myData = nil;
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"WoodTexture"]]];
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Images" ofType:@"plist"];
    myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundle];
    [self setImageswithOptions];
    count = 0;
    score = 0;
    [self resetScreen];
}
```

The method definition goes below.

```
- (void)setImageswithOptions
{
    NSInteger number[4],i;
    for ( i = 0; i <4 ; ++i ) {
        number[i] = arc4random() % myData.count ;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            if ((number[i] < 0) || (number[i] == number[j] )) {
                --i;
            }
        }
    }
    self.submit.hidden =YES;
    self.displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myData[number[0]]]];
    NSInteger random = arc4random() % 4;
    if (random == 0) {
        random += 1;
    }
    [(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:random] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myData[number[0]]]];
    [(WQZOptionButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:random + 4] setIsCorrect:YES];
    NSInteger imageCount = 0;
    for (NSInteger index = 1; index <= 4; index++) {
        if (index != random) {
            imageCount++;
            [(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:index] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myData[number[imageCount]]]];
            [(WQZOptionButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:index + 4] setIsCorrect:NO];
        }
    }
    [myData removeObjectAtIndex:number[0]];
    self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %ld", (long)score];
}
```

Comment: Explain what you tried, or add some code showing what is not working

Comment: Hello firstly, I have a written a code to take data from a plist and take 4 random values from it as given below. " NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Images" ofType:@"plist"];
    myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundle];
    [self setImageswithOptions]; "

Comment: The method definition is given below..........- (void)setImageswithOptions
{
    NSInteger number[4],i;
    for ( i = 0; i <4 ; ++i ) {
        number[i] = arc4random() % myData.count ;
     
    }
    self.submit.hidden =YES;
    self.displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myData[number[0]]]];
    [(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:random] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myData[number[0]]]];    The last 2 statements assign an image to image view and the correct answer is always given at fist position.

Comment: why don't you use NSSet instead of the myData array.. and you will be sure there the options will be always random.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.

One problem:

```
NSInteger random = arc4random() % 4;
if (random == 0) {
    random += 1;
}
```

`random` will be 1, 2 or 3 and 1 will occur twice as often as 2 or 3.

Also it is better to use `arc4random_uniform()` than the modular operator:
Instead of `arc4random() % 4`
use `arc4random_uniform(4)`